# Elixir: Printing list along with string

Tags: list, printing, elixir

I would like to print a list along with a string identifier like

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
IO.puts "list is ", list
```

This does not work. I have tried few variations like

```
# this prints only the list, not any strings
IO.inspect list
# using puts which also does not work
IO.puts "list is #{list}"
```

In javascript, I could simply do `console.log("list is ", list)`. I'm confused how I could achieve the same in elixir.

Comment: I finally ended up creating  a small logging utility for this - https://hexdocs.pm/slog/readme.html as I need JS type flexible logging without worrying about types. Works fine for me in my dev setup

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Starting with Elixir 1.4, [`IO.inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#inspect/2) accepts `label` option [among others](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Inspect.Opts.html):

```
IO.inspect list, label: "The list is"
#⇒ The list is: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: +1 This is nice! I've written `IO.inspect` wrappers that allow a label but only return the inspected value many times while debugging. No need to do that now! Just throw in `|> IO.inspect(label: "foo")` anywhere to print the value with a label without affecting the behavior of the original code.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe there's a better way (I'm new to Elixir too) but this worked for me:

```
IO.puts(["list is ", Enum.join(list, " ")])                             
list is 1 2 3
```

Interpolation works too:

```
IO.puts("list is #{Enum.join(list, " ")}")
```

**Edit:** [inspect](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Inspect.html#content) seems to better than [Enum.join](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#join/2) for this use case:

```
IO.puts("list is #{inspect(list)}")
list is [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Hmmm ... that seems lot of code just to print something to the console, which we all do very often :)

Comment: To make this fast to type while debugging, I often use `IO.inspect` with a tuple like this: `IO.inspect {:list, list}`. That should print `{:list, [1, 2, 3]}` which is good enough for debugging purposes.